# Popup alert message box

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

When executing this code I get a pop-up, how to make it so that YES option is always selected in or nullify it completely ?

There are already data in the sheet. Do you want to replace them ?

[image: these]

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
                Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                "'" + cell.Value + "'!R10C2:R80C11" _
                , Version:=6)
```

Expects the code in VBA to automatically select "YES".

Comment: try adding Application.DisplayAlerts=False just before that line and then Application.DisplayAlerts=True right after

Comment: Also I was under the impression that "Yes" was always the default?